# Is it "bear" or "bare" with me?

Tags: word-choice, homophones

Is it "bear" or "bare" with me?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

> “Bear with me,” the standard
> expression, is a request for
> forbearance or patience.
>
> “Bare with
> me” would be an invitation to undress.

([*Common Errors in English Usage*](http://www.wsu.edu/%7Ebrians/errors/bare.html), by Paul Brians)

Comment: Think *bear* and as in *bear a burden*.

Answer (score 8):

The phrasal verb is *bear with*, not *bare with*.
*Bear with me* means *have patience with me*, or *be tolerant with me*.