# Is it "bear the shame" or "bare the shame"?

Tags: word-choice, homophones

Google returns results for both variations of this common phrase.

- [bear the shame](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=bear+the+shame&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=bear+the+shame&cp=4&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=bear+the+shame&pbx=1&fp=8ce0e008a607e93d)
- [bare the shame](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=bare+the+shame&btnG=Search)

What is the meaning of this phrase, and which one is correct?  Is the speaker *carrying* their shame or are they *exposing* it?  Or is this just a case of two separate meanings?

Comment: It is the same choice of word as [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it helps to enclose the phrase in quotes when googling:

- ["bear the shame"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bear+the+shame%22) — 607,000
- ["bare the shame"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22bare+the+shame%22) — 83,400

Secondly, having looked through the first 10 pages of the Google results for "bare the shame", *exposing* would not work in most of those contexts at all, it's quite obviously *carrying*. And quite a few of those contexts feature extremely poor grammar and punctuation.

Lastly, while the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 1 cite for "bear the shame", and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/) has 10, neither of them has a single cite for "bare the shame".

So, to me, the answer is pretty clear: "bare" is simply a common misspelling of "bear", whether in the context of this expression [or elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me).

Comment: That's what I said... ;)

Comment: I believe the second line should read: "bare the shame"

Comment: Statistical analysis is great and all, but sometimes analysing the syntax and meaning is much more straightforward. “bear” = “carry”, which fits nicely as a metaphor here. “bare” = “naked” … huh? Furthermore, “to bear” as a verb fits syntactically. “bare” as an adjective is syntactically awkward and usage as a verb seems to be virtually non-existent, and looking at contexts shows that “bare (sic) the shame” is *never* used in a way that could mean “to expose the shame”.

Answer (score 3):

The common phrase is 'bear the shame', as in carrying the shame. The prevalance of 'bare' on Google is probably a result of misspelling. You would probably say something more like:

> He *laid* bare the shame of corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting to note. I don't have any verification of this, but I'm pretty sure the original root for this phrase is from the Bible. When Cain killed Abel and G-d chastised him, he (Cain) says "גָּדוֹל עֲו‍ֹנִי, מִנְּשֹׂא" (gadol avoni minso) - My sin is too great to bear. The word מִנְּשֹׂא (minso) literally means to carry.

Comment: Indeed, the actual phrase "bear shame" is found in a few places in the King James Version, as a literal translation of the Hebrew נשא כלמה: Ezek. 36:6-7 and 44:15.

Comment: Interesting, but I suggest that “to carry” is simply a convenient metaphor here, it’s used in all kinds of completely unrelated places in the same way. I think the same is true here.